# Replace space of multiple files inside Google Cloud Storage

Tags: json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have thousands of jsons on google cloud storage, but they have a specific field name (campaign name)
with a space, but before load (or create an external table) on bigquery I need to replace the space for underscore (campaign_name). I'm getting the following error when I try to create without replace:
Error in query string: Illegal field name: campaign name Table: raw_km_all_data

Is there any other solution that not includes download all the files to a server, do the replace and then upload again to cloud storage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pretend that these JSON files are CSV with single column containing big string. Then, once it is loaded into BigQuery as a single column table - use [REPLACE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#replace) or [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace) functions to replace spaces with underscores. Then you can use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#json-functions) family of functions to parse JSON and populate table with real columns.